# How to calculate $\int_C \cos \big( \cos \frac 1z \big) dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, residue-calculus, singularity

The question says:

If $C$ is a closed curve enclosing origin in the positive sense. Then $\int_C \cos \big( \cos \frac 1z \big) dz=$ ?

$(1)\quad 0$

$(2)\quad 2\pi i$

$(3) \quad \pi i$

$(4)\quad -\pi i$

My thoughts :-

I am having trouble identifying the singularity type of
$f(z)= \cos \big( \cos \frac 1z \big)$  at $z=0$. I know that $\cos (\frac 1z)$ has an essential singularity at zero. So is it valid to conclude that $f(z)$ also has essential singularity at zero by saying

" Since $\lim_{z\to 0}\cos (\frac 1z)$ does not exist , then $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$ also does not exist . "

Assuming I am correct, to calculate the integral, I just need to find the coefficient of $\frac 1z$ to apply Residue Theorem, Right ?

Now $f(z)=\cos \big( \cos (\frac 1z) \big)=1-\frac {\cos^2 (\frac 1z)}{2!} +\frac {\cos^4 (\frac 1z)}{4!}-...   $

$=1-\frac 12 \big(1-\frac 1{2!z^2}+...\big)^2 + \frac 1{24}\big(1-\frac 1{2!z^2}+...\big)^4  $

So the coefficient of $\frac 1z$ is zero.

So my answer is $(1)$ , right ?

Any corrections or alternative ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: i dont quite understand you $C$. I mean you want it to enclose the origin right? So do we have $C : [0,t] \to \mathbb R^2$? If thats the case how is $\frac{1}{z}$ defined and how does $cos$ act on $\mathbb  R^2$

Comment: Sorry , I didn't understand your question  either.  $\frac 1z$  is not defined for $z=0$  , that's why I said there is a singularity and why can't $\cos $ act on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (supposing it as isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$) ?

Comment: there is no canonial generalization of cosine to multidimensional domains or do you know one?
Is $C:[0,t] \to \mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is the correct answer. But the sentence in quotation                                                                          marks is not correct. You can say that $f(\frac  1 {2n\pi})=\cos 1$ and $f(\frac  1 {(2n+1)\pi/2})=\cos 0=1 \neq \cos 1$  so $f$ has an essential singularity since it is neither true that $f$ has  a finite limit at $0$ nor is it true that $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $z \to 0$. .

Comment: Yes , Thank you .

Answer (score 3):

Your function is an even function. Therefore, the coefficient of $\frac1z$ is $0$, and so your integral is equal to $0$ too.